# Excel VBA - data validation for specific range

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I have MyRange (i.e. B3:P100, but it varies). I'd like to limit the user input in this range (i.e. data validation): leave the cell empty or enter an "X" and displaying an error message in case of a different character typed.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Test()
    Range("B3:P100").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=OR(B3="""",B3=""X"")"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, your code works great.
I have run-time 1004 "error in select method for Range class" (translated from Italian) when I replace "Range("B3:P100").Select" with "students.Range(MyNegRange).Select".
"students" is my students' sheet, MyNegRange is a range for grades and both work in other parts of my VBA code.

Comment: I got it work with "With students.Range(MyNegRange).Validation"